# How can I use merge() in R to merge data frames on columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an empty data frame called "weatherDataFinal" that I've initialized with the following columns:
"visibility", "cloudCover", "pressure", "windSpeed" and "windBearing"

Now I have three other data frames:

```
Obs1  
visibility   cloudCover   pressure
        10         0.03    1014.06

Obs2
windSpeed   windBearing
    16.27           280

Obs3
visibility   pressure
      2.97    1010.04
```

I need to combine these three data frames in such a manner that the data points go under the proper columns regardless of their number or position in the data frame such that "weatherDataFinal" winds up looking like this:

```
visibility   cloudCover   pressure   windSpeed   windBearing
        10         0.03    1014.06
                                         16.27           280
      2.97                 1010.04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1 <- read.table(text="visibility,cloudCover,pressure
10,0.03,1014.06", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",")

d2 <- read.table(text="windSpeed,windBearing
16.27,280", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",")

d3 <- read.table(text="visibility,pressure
2.97,1010.04", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",")

dplyr::rbind_list(d1, d2, d3)
## Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
## 
##   visibility cloudCover pressure windSpeed windBearing
##        (dbl)      (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl)       (int)
## 1      10.00       0.03  1014.06        NA          NA
## 2         NA         NA       NA     16.27         280
## 3       2.97         NA  1010.04        NA          NA
```

Comment: I have to create a blank data frame and initialize it with all the expected columns. I've set every column to character. I get:
Error: incompatible type (data index: 2, column: 'time', was collecting: character (dplyr::Collecter_Impl<16>), incompatible with data of type: POSIXct, POSIXt

Comment: It would help, then, if you gave us the real data you are using. `dplyr` won't work with `POSIXlt` structures.

Comment: I can't because I'm calling an API and you'd need to get an API key, however, I was able to develop a solution based on your idea. Thanks!